# random characters showing up SOMETIMES in my file once I write and create it

Tags: c

Using the system call write, sometimes only, when I write the file I see garbage like this in my text file. What could be the reason? The program is too large to share.

^D^H ª^D^H^A
^D^H ª^D^H^A Hi How are you

Even though all I wrote was Hi How Are you

Comment: You have an error on line 42 of the file....oh, sorry, my crystal ball is getting hazy; I can't quite see the file name with no hint of the code to work from.

Comment: no code == no answers (obviously). Perhaps you have a buffer overrun somewhere....

Comment: Do you think you could derive a testcase from your program? If not, then perhaps the more significant problem is that your software development methodology needs refining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some things I would check:

- Maybe you're opening the file in append mode when there already is some garbage text in it?
- Maybe your buffer from which you're writing has not been initialized properly?

Nobody can really give you any solid answers if you don't at least provide some pseudocode of what you're doing.